# Creating an animated slide-down menu using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to upgrade my app to use Autolayout, basically to be future-proof, but I'm running into a huge amount of problems TRYING to use autolayout.

[image: Autolayout mess]

What I have is a view controller which contains two UINavigationControllers (using view controller containment). If I press a button, I want the menu to come down. Within the menu, i'll push view controllers and whatever else, and if the user wants to quickly get out of the menu they can tap the bottom part of the view at the bottom. Basically, if you've used Uber, something similar to that.

I have fiddled and fiddled but I can't get it to work correctly. The best I got was set up a XIB for the container view, and have two views within it (as well as a few outlets for some constraints). Within code, I change the constants of these constraints to make the menu view move and to force the correct height of the menu (which is the same as the bottom minus an offset).

The problem comes in when I try to push another view controller in the menu as it seems to throw away the height constraint set on the menu -- new view controllers take up the entire screen. I don't want to use clipSubviews because that doesn't really solve the problem, and sometimes I use overlays which need to go outside of the view.

To be honest, I don't even really care that much if this animation even uses autolayout, but I want to be able to use it on the view controllers within each navigation controller. Right now, if I turn it on, the animation won't work at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're more concerned with is getting that menu view to slide down, correct? If so I recommend using the [REMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu) control, which easily implements what you want without having to worry about autolayout (at least for this).

Comment: No, because I want a navigation controller in the top view as well as the bottom view. Not a basic menu which changes the bottom view.